# com.cloudant.spark data source not found in DSX Notebook

Tags: data-science-experience, spark-cloudant

I'm trying  to follow https://developer.ibm.com/clouddataservices/docs/ibm-data-science-experience/docs/load-and-filter-cloudant-data-with-spark/ to load cloudant data with Spark. I have a Scala 2.11 with Spark 2.1 (happens with Spark 2.0 as well) notebook with the following code in it:

```
// @hidden_cell
var credentials = scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[String, String](
  "username"->"<redacted>",
  "password"->"""<redacted>""",
  "host"->"<redacted>",
  "port"->"443",
  "url"->"<redacted>"
)
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
val cloudantdata = sqlContext.read.format("com.cloudant.spark").
option("cloudant.host", credentials("host")).
option("cloudant.username", credentials("username")).
option("cloudant.password", credentials("password")).
load("crimes")
```

Trying to execute that cell only ends in

> Name: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
>   Message: Failed to find data source: com.cloudant.spark. Please find packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html
>   StackTrace:   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:569)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.providingClass$lzycompute(DataSource.scala:86)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.providingClass(DataSource.scala:86)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:325)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:152)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:135)
>     ... 42 elided
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.cloudant.spark.DefaultSource
>     at scala.reflect.internal.util.AbstractFileClassLoader.findClass(AbstractFileClassLoader.scala:62)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:844)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:823)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:803)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$25$$anonfun$apply$13.apply(DataSource.scala:554)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$25$$anonfun$apply$13.apply(DataSource.scala:554)
>     at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$25.apply(DataSource.scala:554)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$25.apply(DataSource.scala:554)
>     at scala.util.Try.orElse(Try.scala:84)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:554)

How can I get past this error and connect to my Cloudant database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There must have been some issue that caused cloudant driver to be missing which is typically by default present in DSX Notebook.
Please change to python 2.0 and spark 2.1 kernel
and run this one time installation(per spark service) of cloudant connector so that it will be available for all your spark 2.0+ kernels.

```
!pip install --upgrade pixiedust
```

`import pixiedust`

```
pixiedust.installPackage("cloudant-labs:spark-cloudant:2.0.0-s_2.11")
```

Restart kernel once.

Then change the kernel to your scala kernel and then run your cloudant connection code.

Thanks,
Charles.